# To get a specific child in unty 3d

Tags: c#, object, scripting, unity-game-engine, parent-child

I know the parent name.

I have to rotate a specific child of the parent.

But I'm getting an error in c#.

How can I change this code to c#?

```
aFinger = transform.Find("LeftShoulder/Arm");
aFinger.Rotate(Time.deltaTime*20, 0, 0);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i need c # code.. Above code is javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify how aFinger is defined, I'll assume it's a `var` that will cause it to be whatever is correct.

Try `aFinger.transform.Rotate(Time.deltaTime*20,0,0);`

Answer (score 1):

You want that code in C#:

```
GameObject aFinger = transform.Find("LeftShoulder/Arm");
aFinger.Rotate(Time.deltaTime*20, 0,0);
```

Please tell us on what you have already tried and what result you got. Converting from Javascript to C# is usually not that hard...

Comment: aFinger.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 330, 0);                         this was i tried for . anyway thanks 4 everyone

Comment: You really need to explain your questions better. Your solution is nowhere near the answer to your question.

Comment: i specified that i just want to rotate a child

Comment: No, that wasn't the question. You posted some JavaScript code and the question was: `How can I change this code to c#?`

Comment: i specified in second line :)

Comment: And you say in the third line you have an error in your code. Then you show us the code. In that code, you try to rotate a child object. You ASK us to convert that script for you, since it gives an error (which one???) when you try it. So the question is answered with that script converted. I'm just trying to explain how SO works.